# Error when Connecting PowerBI to Snowflake

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am receiving an error when connecting Power BI to Snowflake.

"Unable to Connect - We encountered an error while trying to connect.  Details: "The server name should only be a host name".

I am putting our server in as:

https://xxxxxx.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

And I have put in the name of the Warehouse (compute) that I want to use to process the load:

PRD_BI_GENERAL_US_XS

I chose Import mode and left all the optional fields blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either from Power BI Desktop or Power BI service, the target Server when connecting to a Snowflake account has to be the hostname, therefore it doesn't need the HTTPS:// which instead is required to get to the Snowflake Account via Web UI.

An example would be: `contoso.snowflakecomputing.com`

Also, in order to successfully connect from Power BI you have to impersonate a Snowflake Role that is allowed 'Usage' permission on the Virtual Warehouse and the Database you want to get to. This can be done by having that specific Role as the Default Role for your Login.
Note that, since February 2021, Power BI Desktop supports Snowflake custom roles.

Reference:

- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-snowflake#:~:text=To%20connect%20to%20a%20Snowflake,the%20box%20and%20select%20O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-snowflake#:%7E:text=To%20connect%20to%20a%20Snowflake,the%20box%20and%20select%20O)
- https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-february-2021-feature-summary/#_Toc63074806
  .

Comment: Thank you @FrancescoQuaratino.  That worked!  I think that SuzyLockwood's (why can't you @ more than one person?) answer was also correct but I chose your's as the answer because of the the thoroughness of the explanation and because I think that the extra Role and Usage information was pertinent

Comment: Of course, thanks @Jerid421. Speaking about Roles, note that Power BI Desktop now supports custom roles (since the Feb 2021 update) https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-february-2021-feature-summary/#_Toc63074806

Answer (score 3):

Try it without the "https://":

xxxxxx.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com